# Strings and the Uncertainty Principle

Tags: string-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I understand that the problem with fundamental particles is that they are $0$-dimensional and therefore infinitesimal in size. This seems unphysical and leads to infinities in calculations.

The advantage of strings is that as they are $1$-dimensional they do have a finite size.

Do strings obey the following version of the uncertainty principle?

Uncertainty in length $\times$ uncertainty in vibrational momentum $\sim$ $\hbar$

Answer (score 4):

No.

The uncertainty principle is a general relation between expectation values of quantum mechanical *operators* - the [Robertson-Schrödinger uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations). The string length is not an operator in string theory, it's just a constant $\propto \sqrt{\alpha'}$, where $\alpha' = \frac1{2\pi T}$ for the tension $T$ that appears as the free multiplicative parameter in the [Polyakov action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyakov_action)
$$ S_P[h,X] = -\frac{T}{2}\int_\Sigma\sqrt{h}h^{ab}\partial_aX^\mu\partial_bX_\mu.$$
Constants do not fulfill uncertainty relations.